# How to push all user input at a time in a single row to a Linked List in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list, user-input, singly-linked-list

Here's the code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.last_node = None

    def prepend(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node

    def push(self, data):
        if self.last_node is None:
            self.head = Node(data)
            self.last_node = self.head
        else:
            self.last_node.next = Node(data)
            self.last_node = self.last_node.next

    def insert_after(self, prev_node, data):
        if not prev_node:
            print('Given node not present in the list')
            return
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.next = prev_node.next
        prev_node.next = new_node

    def pswap(self):
        temp = self.head
        if temp is None:
            return

        while (temp is not None and temp.next is not None):
            temp.data, temp.next.data = temp.next.data, temp.data
            temp = temp.next.next

    def display(self):
        current = self.head
        while current:
            print(current.data, end=' ')
            current = current.next


llist = LinkedList()
T = int(input())
for x in range(T):
    d = int(input())
    llist.push(d)

llist.display()
llist.pswap()
print()
llist.display()
```

Here I am able to pass in this way:
4 => No. of elements u want to enter
1
2
3
4
But I want to give user input in this manner:
4 => No. of elements u want to enter
1 2 3 4

Answer (score 0):

The simplest implementation could be just to `split` the string provided by the user:

```
llist = LinkedList()
T = int(input("Number of elements: "))
data = input("Space-separated numbers: ")
numbers = map(int, data.split())

for d in numbers:
    llist.push(d)
```

This ignores the number of elements `T` provided by the user, but you could incorporate this information by asking the user to input more data if they haven't inputted enough or by notifying then that excess data won't be processed:

```
T = int(input("Number of elements: "))
data = []
while len(data) < T:
    data.extend(map(int, input("Space-separated numbers: ").split()))

if len(data) > T:
    print(f"Too much data entered, its length will be cut to {T}")

for d in data[:T]:
    llist.push(d)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I was stuck in this for quite a while.